# Popups offset from points Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, popup, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I've been playing a lot with mapbox for mapping some data of mine. I have created a map that is heavily borrowed from the original mapbox sweetgreen tutorial [here](https://www.mapbox.com/help/building-a-store-locator/). However, now that I am almost finished, I am finding that my popups are not lining up well with my points. They are offset fairly heavily from them. I've played around with the CSS a bit but to no avail. Ideas?

Code related to popups:

CSS:

```
.mapboxgl-popup-close-button {
  display: none;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content {
  font: 400 15px/22px 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  width: 180px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content-wrapper {
  padding: 1%;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content h3 {
  background: #91c949;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content h4 {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-content div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.mapboxgl-container .leaflet-marker-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top > .mapboxgl-popup-content {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.mapboxgl-popup-anchor-top > .mapboxgl-popup-tip {
  border-bottom-color: #91c949;
}
```

Script:

```
 function createPopUp(currentFeature) {
    var popUps = document.getElementsByClassName('mapboxgl-popup');
    if (popUps[0]) popUps[0].remove();


    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({closeOnClick: false})
      .setLngLat(currentFeature.geometry.coordinates)
      .setHTML('<h3><a href=' + currentFeature.properties.URL + '>' + currentFeature.properties.Company + '</a></h4>'+ currentFeature.properties.City + ", " + currentFeature.properties.State + '</p>' + "Phone: " + currentFeature.properties.Phone + '</p>')
      .addTo(map);
  }
```

[Image of offset problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRJN7.jpg)

Comment: I think the option you are looking for is the popup's "anchor". Mapbox is based on Leaflet, so you might get some ideas from Leaflet documentation as well.

Comment: Or possibly the "offset" option, as used in that Store Locator tutorial like this: 
`new mapboxgl.Marker(el, {offset: [0, -23]})
        .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
        .addTo(map);`

Comment: @cmrRose the is using Mapbox GL JS, which isn't based on Leaflet, looking at the Leaflet documentation might just make them more confused.

Comment: @StupidQuestionGuy could you post a jsbin, etc of your code?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an 'offset' value on the first line of the popup variable like so:

```
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: [20, 0]})
```

Or if you need to add more properties, such as 'closeOnClick':

```
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({closeOnClick: true, offset: [20, 0]})
```